# Choose Datasource file in iMacros javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am trying to make iMacros script to enable user to choose datasource file at the beginning.

This is one solution I found and it works:

var sourcefile = prompt("Enter file location");

and then I use variable as {{sourcefile}} in script.

macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE {{sourcefile}}" + "\n";

The problem is that in this case the user has to enter full path and filename.
I want to change javascript code so users will have Browse button and can select datasource file by clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code instead of a `prompt`-dialogue:

```
var sourcefile = imns.Dialogs.browseForFileOpen("Enter file location");
if (sourcefile)
    sourcefile = sourcefile.path;
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you Shugar, that was magnificent :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better with filetype (like *.csv):

```
// imacros imns.Dialogs.browseForFileOpen() does not provide a way to appendFilter 
var fp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker);

// initial directory use Macros folder as defined in iMacros Preferences
fp.displayDirectory = imns.Pref.getFilePref('defsavepath');//DataSources=defdatapath
fp.init(window, "Select a File", Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker.modeOpen);
fp.appendFilter("CSV File (*.csv)", "*.csv");

var sourcefile;
if(fp.show() == 0){
    sourcefile = fp.file.path;
}
```

Comment: This works great. I like possibility of changing the default folder to be Datasources.